# Recording time series data from Bluetooth by Pybluez

Tags: bluetooth, python-3

I am currently work in a project that I am using Raspberry-pi to record data from Bluetooth signal. I chosen the PyBluez to program bluetooth. My object is to write the data into csv file, each data point corresponding to the time it was recorded.

I connect the Bluetooth by following code:

```
port = 1
target_addr = '20:17:08:15:12:41'
sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((target_addr, port)
```

The first way I used to print the signal is `sock.recv(1024)` and It returned a huge string `'-10245\r\n,Red:-10285\r\n,Red:-2918\r\n...'` I cannot match each data point into the corresponding time I received it. So I tried the second way which I tried to use readline() function, I convert socket into file and use readline() to read each data value: `f = sock.makefile("r+")` then `f.readline()`, the result is not consistence : `ed:3124\r\n`, `Red:-4480\r\n`, `1\r\n`, `:-4480\r\n`. Can anyone suggest the way I can read the bluetooth which I can receive a proper string value ex: `Red:34612\r\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide the full program so it is hard to know what you are missing, but I think you probably setting up the client mix up the client/server relationship.

```
import bluetooth

# setup server
port = 1
target_addr = '20:17:08:15:12:41'
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
sock.bind((target_addr,port))
sock.listen(1)

# setup client
client_sock,address = sock.accept()
print "Accepted connection from ",address

data = client_sock.recv(1024)
print "received [%s]" % data

client_sock.close()
sock.close()
```

Comment: Thanks hceung, I tried `bind` and `listen` before, but the line `sock.accept`  run for a long time and did not end. That why I switch to `sock.connect(addr)`. Do you know why the line `sock.accept` keep running without end ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can read each value from Bluetooth now, I saw the data in consistence so I put a small delay: `time.sleep(0.01)` then the code `f.readline()` returned perfect values.